# Git deployment of October CMS site

Tags: php, git, web-deployment, octobercms

I set up Git deployment for most of my sites and it work really well. I have recently started to work with October, and for main pages which I create myself, I would like to work locally and then use Git to deploy new and updated pages to the live server.

It is my understanding that (apart from blog plugins for instance) October uses flat files for it's content. If I create files locally within my local install of October, can I safely Git push only the files I have worked on (html, css, js etc.) up to the site along with front matter and have them work on the remote deployment server? Will October just integrate them?

Comment: Yes you can, it would be no different to any other script.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I'll at least check it out so. I was afraid of messing something up on the server if I tried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use git to deploy your site content and manage it via version control.

You can set your *.gitignore* to the following folders

```
.DS_Store
*.log
/vendor
/storage
/plugins/october
/modules/**/*
/config
/bootstrap
/themes/demo
artisan
index.php
.htaccess
```

And it will upload the text/theme files you add/commit.

After the *git pull* you might wish to do a cache refresh

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

or install the cache clear widget(https://octobercms.com/plugin/romanov-clearcachewidget)

Comment: Marking this as correct because of the extra .gitignore info which I really needed to make this happen